# AppCache on Android Devices

Tags: android, html, application-cache, html5-appcache

I have this weird problem in trying out an appCache website on android phones.  I've tested it in a Froyo 2.2 Android device.  I'm testing the capability of AppCache on Android phones using this AppCache demo http://people.opera.com/shwetankd/demos/2/index.htm

I've tested it using Dolphin Browser and it works.  Problem arise when I'm testing it in the default browser of Android.

So I visit the page, then turn off my internet connection.  Then I reload the page, it will display message like Page not Found with the URL appended on the message.  Thing is when I click that same URL that is in the error message, it loads the cached page.  Same thing when I new tab the page, it works.

It just won't work on visiting-the-page -> turning-off-internet -> reloading existing page.

Any ideas?  Or is it just my test device?  Thanks.

Comment: Seems like it's just a bug in default browser. Obviously it ignores the appcache when the previous load of the page was successful and tries again over network.

Comment: @MEB Have you tried it in an Android device as well?

Comment: Yes. Tried on Desktop (Firefox) and Android 2.3.5 (FF, Dolphin, default) -> works fine, instead with default-browser: a simple reload of the site after disconnecting get the output you've concerned about – after closing and entering the URL again: no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems correct behavior to me: When you use reload, you ask the browser to reload the page, meaning "fetch it from the Internet".

If you go the the page normally, you just want the page and the app cache is good enough.

Now, it may make sense to honor the app cache even for reloads, to avoid confusion, but then you'd need another way (like Ctrl-F5 on desktop browsers) to express "No, I really meant I want you to download an entirely new copy".

Pick your cancer: User confusion, or new controls (which could also lead to user confusion).

(I realize this is almost a year old, but I just stumbled upon it)